# In Opengl,are Near plane and Image plane same things?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm an Android developer but a beginner of OpenGL. I'm confused by the view frustum.
There are two questions:

1. Are near plane and picture plane same things?
2. If they are not same things, why there isn't a z-value of the picture plane to be specified?

I'm not proficient in English, hope you can understand my questions ..Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I've never completely finished it, but I've written a illustrative program that tries to explain, what the frustum is: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum

Answer (score 8):

No, they're different concepts and an image plane isn't needed in OpenGL.

Near and far planes exist as a result of using a projection matrix to define the camera's projection. They're quite important when you get into the depth buffer and numerical accuracy. The image is the result of rendering, obviously. The image plane however only exists in real world cameras where light is projected through a pinhole or lens and onto the thing recording the image. In computer graphics it's not really necessary to model it unless you're doing crazy non-thin lens effects. I imagine it like this:

[image]

Again, the parts circled "imaginary" don't have any purpose in OpenGL and rasterization. They're necessary for a real camera, but artificially computing an image can take some shortcuts. Firstly, the projection matrix is used to project geometry into image space, keeping depth values. Image space is pretty separate to the concept of the image plane. We don't tend to think of the position and size of the sensor or film in a camera when looking at a photo. The geometry's then rasterized, producing fragments (packets of data for pixels). The depth buffer is used to keep only the front-most, visible, fragments. This is just based on depth comparisons. In one sense a pixel isn't a surface on an explicit image plane, but represents a cut out portion of the viewing volume.

The wiki page for [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics) discusses the mapping of points onto the plane z = 1, though arguing this is the depth of the image plane doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

There's a bunch of literature about camera models out there, but I don't know which I should point out. If others do, please comment/edit! Perhaps start with the red book? http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html

Comment: But the "glViewport" function works on the near plane ,doesn't it? so the viewport is a piece of region of near plane.

Comment: @user911660 No, `glViewport` defines the area within the window to render to. Its with/height become the resolution of the image you generate using OpenGL. The projection defines how geometry gets stretched and transformed before being rasterized to the viewport. Near and far planes just clip the geometry and provide a bounded depth range. It might not hurt to visualize the viewport on an image plane, stretched to the frustum sides, on or behind the near plane (as in the image) and rays shooting out from each pixel but I'd caution against it in case it enables more confusion.

Comment: @jozxyqk There is still some sort of focal length implicitly embedded in the perspective matrix. That is, the "focal length" or distance from the camera to the image plane is derived from the specified field of view in the (fovy). See line 241 at https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.9.8/glm/ext/matrix_clip_space.inl for example.

Comment: @Sam Yes, a perspective projection has a definite FOV. focal length is a function of a lens. Focal length affects the FOV (although the FOV changes slightly as you adjust the focus because the sensor/film size is constant) but so does the sensor/film, e.g. full frame vs aps-c standard sizes. Unless modelling lens effects I think the concept of an image plane can add confusion. Better to think of pixels coordinates in the rendered image mapping to a direction/angle rather than a position on an imaginary plane.